# Pass dynamic number to loader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a simple question. How to pass dynamic number to loader manager? Thanks!

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    loader.load(url[i], function ( texture ) {
        console.log(i)
        textures[i] = texture;
    });
}

// console.log(i)  ->  3, 3, 3
// i need          ->  0, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using ecmascript 2015 is an option, just ùse the keyword `let` instead of `var` in the for loop:

```
for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
    ...
}
```

This will allow the variable `i` to be *block scoped* instead of *function scoped*.

Explanation to ths behaviour can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479554/3346060)